# Не уходят письма c сервера Zimbra

Tags: zimbra

Установлен и давно работает сервер на `Zimbra`. Появилась проблема, при отправке писем на один из доменов почта не всегда проходит. Я пробил домен на сайте на `http://mxtoolbox.com` (тестирует почтовые сервера) и получил результат.

```
smtp    mx2.!!!.!!!.ru  Reverse DNS does not match SMTP Banner   
smtp    mx2.!!!.!!!.ru  Warning - Does not support TLS.      
smtp    mx2.!!!.!!!.ru  15.425 seconds - Not good! on Transaction Time
```

Думаю что на сервере `mx2.!!!.!!!.ru` установили режим `"Tarpitting"` (задержанного ответа на прием письма).

Вопрос как установить длительность транзакции на сервере `Zimbra` чтобы решить данную проблему.